# Iphone middleware/client area in Wordpress CMS?

Tags: iphone, ios, wordpress, middleware

I have a team of developers working on Iphone apps for multiple clients.. I was wondering if anyone has experience creating the middleware/client area in Wordpress and therefore facilitating easy client interaction with the backend system..

Whats the best way to have the iphone app talk to this purposed middleware/client area?

For exaxmple, a client would be able to add a product to an app via wordpress or change text around ect.

Comment: I'm confused - what does your team of developers working on apps have to do with WordPress? I can't tell what the meat of your question is - are you asking what protocol to use to communicate with WP? Are you trying to talk directly to WP or to some middleware - the last line seems to indicate your app is working directly with WP.

Comment: Sorry about that... Either directly with WP or a middleware if required.. whats the easiest solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking what is the easier method of making an iOS application talk to WordPress for doing admin and CMS functions, I think middleware is going to be easier. Reason being, if a WordPress hot fix or upgrade with new feature X comes out and changes the API, you don't have to republish your iOS app (the most painful part of iOS development) - you just make a change to your middleware and everything keeps ticking.

Comment: Thanks!... That being said, are there any established middleware solutions that can serve as an intermediary between these two platforms?